# deleting array content which matches with an other array

Tags: powershell

the goal of my script is to copy some files. i import a config file, which gives me the path and a filename for an exclude (the exclude shouldnt get copied).

now, i have 2 arrays, one for the folders and one for the excludes and i want to delete all rows from the array1 which contain the exclude file from array2.

i tried something like this but it has not worked...

```
$arrFolder = $arrFolder - $arrExcludes
```

or

```
$arrFolder | $_ -replace "$arrExcludes",""
```

i was searching for houres with no good solution. can anybody help me?

thank you & regards, mischa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Except from LINQ (PS 3.0+):

```
$arr1 = "Folder1", "Folder2", "Folder3", "Folder4"
$arr2 = "Folder2", "Folder3"

[System.Linq.Enumerable]::Except([string[]]$arr1, [string[]]$arr2)
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many classic and trivial loop-based solutions, for example:

```
$arrFolder = $arrFolder | ?{ $_ -notin $arrExcludes }
```

Usually, this is what you'd want, unless the arrays are *very* big or you do a lot of iterations.
In that case here's a different one using .NET [HashSet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) class that works in modern PowerShell 4.0+:

```
$arrHash = [Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$arrFolder
$arrHash.ExceptWith([Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]$arrExcludes)
$arrFolder = @($arrHash)
```